# agora npm start command gives me error with Error: spawn cd ENOENT

Tags: npm, agora.io, agora-implementation, agora

agora npm start command gives me error with Error: spawn cd ENOENT
can any one help me

`E:\Projects\Full Stack Projects\Video App by Alpha\agora-app-builder\node_modules\yoga-layout-prebuilt\yoga-layout\build\Release\nbind.js:53
throw ex;
^

Error: spawn cd ENOENT
at notFoundError (E:\Projects\Full Stack Projects\Video App by Alpha\agora-app-builder\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:6:26)
at verifyENOENT (E:\Projects\Full Stack Projects\Video App by Alpha\agora-app-builder\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:40:16)
at ChildProcess.cp.emit (E:\Projects\Full Stack Projects\Video App by Alpha\agora-app-builder\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:27:25)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
at ChildProcess.cp.emit (E:\Projects\Full Stack Projects\Video App by Alpha\agora-app-builder\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:30:37)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12) {
code: 'ENOENT',
errno: 'ENOENT',
syscall: 'spawn cd',
path: 'cd',
spawnargs: [ 'videoapp', '&&', 'npm', 'install' ]
}`

I run `npm start` after `npm i` and show me this error while I try many times as well with cmd admin